# Want use a Jquery dialog for every Database ID using foreach

Tags: php, jquery

I want a JQuery dialog for every Database row.

My problem with this is that when I want to click on something. all dialog opens for every ID [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzNQn.png). I want that when clicked it only shows that specific ID.
I've never really worked with JQuery, I've searched a lot but I'm just out of ideas how I can fix this problem.

My code:

Query.

```
 <?php
  include ('functions/function.php');
  $connect = connectToDB();

 $query = "SELECT `MaasduinId`, `MaasduinImage`, `MaasduinNaam`, 
 `MaasduinLocatie`, `MaasduinTelefoon`, `MaasduinEmail`, `MaasduinWebsite`, 
 `MaasduinWelkom`, `MaasduinArrangement`,`MaasduinPasfoto` ,`MaasduinPas`, 
 `MaasduinCategory` FROM `maasduinen` WHERE 1=1";

$resource = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$hotels = array();

while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resource))
{
$hotels[] = $result; // all your games are now in array $games
}


?>
```

For each loop with the script inside

```
                foreach($hotels as $key => $hotel)
                {
                    ?>
                    <?php if ($hotel['MaasduinCategory'] == 'Appartementen'): ?>

                            <div class="products-<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinId'];?>">
                                <div class="maasduin-foto"><img style="width: 136px; height: 134px;" src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinImage']; ?>">
                                    <?php if ($hotel['MaasduinPas'] == '1'): ?>
                                        <div class="maasduin-actiefoto">
                                            <img style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinPasfoto']; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="maasduin-naam"><?php echo 
                                 $hotel['MaasduinNaam']; ?></h3></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-locatie"><?php echo 
                                 $hotel['MaasduinLocatie']; ?></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-email"><?php echo 
                                  $hotel['MaasduinEmail']; ?></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-telefoon"><?php echo 
                                  $hotel['MaasduinTelefoon']; ?></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-website"><?php echo 
                                  $hotel['MaasduinWebsite']; ?></div>
                    <script>
                            var $dialog; 
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                $dialog = $("div[class^='test-']")

                                .dialog({
                                    autoOpen: false,
                                    title: '<?php echo 
                                    $hotel['MaasduinNaam']; ?>'
                                });

                                $("div[class^='products-']").click(function () {
                                    $dialog.dialog('open');
                                    return false; ////cancel eventbubbeling
                                });
                            });

                            function showDialog() {
                                $dialog.dialog('open');
                                return false //cancel eventbubbeling
                            }

                    </script>
```

Test- div

```
<?php foreach($hotels as $key => $hotel)
                {
                    ?>
                                <div class="test-<?php echo 
                                  $hotel['MaasduinId'];?>">
                                    <div class="maasduin-naam"><?php echo 
                                      $hotel['MaasduinNaam']; ?></h3></div>
                                </div>

            <?php   } ?>
```

Comment: Just a tip: it's not necessary to use a `WHERE` in your query if you're going to have `WHERE 1=1` since no `WHERE` also selects everything.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
$dialog = $("div[class^='test-']")
```

here you are selecting all the `div's` starting with `test-` in their class name and initialize the dialog on it. Instead of doing this select the particular div by providing them a unique `id` in it and put the dialog initialization code on that `id`. Like:

```
<div class="click_div" id="<?php echo 
  $hotel['MaasduinId'];?>"><?php echo 
  $hotel['MaasduinNaam']; ?></h3>
</div>

$(".click_div").on("click",function(e){
  // $(this).attr('id') will return the id
  $dialog = $(this).attr('id');
  $dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah youre right but how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Thanks, but what can I do to get it clickable again. How to get each https://i.gyazo.com/91adf758041e2a054599df7f5b5c638e.png In the correct dialog?

Comment: Not getting you?

Comment: It looks currently like this : https://i.gyazo.com/91adf758041e2a054599df7f5b5c638e.png How can I make it when I click on .click_div id 1 I get the dialog of id 1?

Comment: I still don't know what to do I've tried alot of things!

Answer (score 0):

Use same class name in every div but id will different :- in your que id will MaasduinId

```
<?php foreach($hotels as $key => $hotel)
                {
                    ?>

                                    <div class="click_div" id="<?php echo 
                                  $hotel['MaasduinId'];?>"><?php echo 
                                      $hotel['MaasduinNaam']; ?></h3></div>


            <?php   } ?>



<script>
$(".click_div").on("click",function(e){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));

});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, how can I get this inside a dialog like before?